# Assign text to a parent's textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Tab Layout that contains a TextView.  I'd like to assign some text at runtime to the TextView.  I thought this would work:

```
    ((TextView)getParent().findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("Some Text");
```

but the text is never set.

This is my layout:

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:padding="0dp"
>
>     <TabWidget
>         android:id="@android:id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>         android:padding="0dp"
>         android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector" 
>      />           
>      <FrameLayout
>         android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:padding="0dp" 
>      />
>         <TextView 
>     android:id="@+id/status"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:text="Last Updated"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:background="#cccccc"
> />         
> </LinearLayout>
>  <RelativeLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>     android:layout_height="10dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">        
> <TextView 
>     android:id="@+id/status"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:background="#cccccc"
>     />
>  </RelativeLayout>
> </TabHost>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
((TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("Some Text");
```

Comment: getParent() is not needed here... just make sure you set the right Layout. (where there is a TextView with Id status)